# Why does SQL Server have multiple cached plans for the same query?

Tags: sql-server

If you `select * from syscacheobjects` you can see some simple stats about your database's queries.  I liked to use this table to find queries to tune.  I especially zero in on queries where `usecounts = 1`.  Sometimes I see two rows for the same query and it's baffled me.

NOTE: The queries are parameterized.

Consider this:

```
| bucketid | cacheobjtype  | objtype  | objid     | dbid | dbidexec | uid | refcounts | usecounts | pagesused | setopts | langid | dateformat | status | lasttime | maxexectime | avgexectime | lastreads | lastwrites | sqlbytes | sql         |
|----------|---------------|----------|-----------|------|----------|-----|-----------|-----------|-----------|---------|--------|------------|--------|----------|-------------|-------------|-----------|------------|----------|-------------|
| 7650     | Compiled Plan | Prepared | 482910160 | 5    | 0        | -2  | 2         | 724       | 21        | 251     | 0      | 1          | 0      | 0        | 0           | 0           | 0         | 0          | 1918     | SELECT blah |
| 7650     | Compiled Plan | Prepared | 482910160 | 5    | 0        | -2  | 7         | 705505    | 81        | 251     | 0      | 1          | 0      | 0        | 0           | 0           | 0         | 0          | 1918     | SELECT blah |
```

Everything is the same except the refcounts and usecounts column.

So why are there two rows?

**UPDATE**

One also gets the same more-than-one-row situation from the new management schema.  The engine really is creating more than once cached plan.  Anyone know why?

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans PLANS
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (PLANS.plan_handle) AS Q
where [text] like '%SOMETHING%'
order by [text]

vs

select * 
from syscacheobjects 
where sql like '%SOMETHING%'
order by [sql]
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using it anyway see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql

Comment: Well, it shows the exact same thing as those other tables.  I've updated the question.

Comment: In this case, the queries are parameterized.  All the where clause values are in parameters.

Answer (score 3):

> Everything is the same except the refcounts and usecounts column

This is not true. Your plans are different and you can see it looking at `pagesused` and `setopts` columns.

The first one is Number of pages consumed by the cache object, so you can clearly see that one plan is bigger. The second columns, setopts, is the key one, this is the cause of having two different plans for the same query. Here is BOL description of this column:

> SET option settings that affect a compiled plan. These settings are
>   part of the cache key. Changes to values in this column indicate users
>   have modified SET options.

As you can see, two plans are made for 2 different sets of session options, 21 and 81.

21 means these options are on:

```
ANSI_PADDING

ANSI_WARNINGS

FORCEPLAN
```

81 means these options are on:

```
ANSI_PADDING

ANSI_WARNINGS

QUOTED_IDENTFIER
```

> When FORCEPLAN is set to ON, the SQL Server query optimizer processes
>   a join in the same order as the tables appear in the FROM clause of a
>   query. In addition, setting FORCEPLAN to ON forces the use of a nested
>   loop join unless other types of joins are required to construct a plan
>   for the query, or they are requested with join hints or query hints.

So you see that your plans are different as one of them has `FORCED ORDER` and other no.

`Set options` make part of cache key, this means if you have two sessions that have different set options, 2 plans (same or different) will be made. When another session tries to exec the same query its set options define what plan will be used, and if these options are different from those that are already in cache, the third plan will be created and cached for this query and this third set of session options.

You can read more on it here: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

**UPDATE**

The answer is still in the article cited above.

> **When there is more than one entry in the cache for the same procedure**, the entries have at least one difference in the **cache
>   keys**. A cache key is a run-time setting, which for one reason or
>   another calls for a different query plan. Most of these settings are
>   controlled with a SET command, but not all.

...

> A very important cache
>   key is `set_options`. This is a bit mask that gives the setting of a
>   number of SET options that can be ON or OFF. If you look further in
>   the topic of sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes, you find a listing that
>   details which SET option each bit describes. (You will also see that
>   there are a few more items that are not controlled by the SET
>   command.) Thus, if two connections have any of these options set
>   differently, the connections will use different cache entries for the
>   same procedure – and therefore they could be using different query
>   plans, with possibly big difference in performance.

First I thought the difference was in `setopts` but they are the same.
Then I understood that `setopts` **does not reflect all the set options**.

For example, `syscacheobjects` does include `dateformat` column, but it's also a set option!

So I just thought about **what is not reflected in `setopts`** but is still `cache key`. And these are, fore example, `compatibility_level` and `date_first`.

I decided to change `date_first` and I was able to reproduce your situation.

I create prepared statement (your plan was for `prepared`) and just change `date_first` from 1 to 7, then I checked `sys.syscacheobjects` and I found 2 plans where all columns was the same as in your case, but you still can find what `cache key` is different in your case using the code from Erland Sommarskog's article:

```
SELECT qs.plan_handle, a.attrlist
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS  APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) est
CROSS  APPLY (SELECT epa.attribute + '=' + convert(nvarchar(127), epa.value) + '   '
              FROM   sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(qs.plan_handle) epa
              WHERE  epa.is_cache_key = 1
              ORDER  BY epa.attribute
              FOR    XML PATH('')) AS a(attrlist)
WHERE est.text like '%2343513B-14B6-4BF3-A262-48F645A35A39%'
  and est.text not like '%syscacheobjects%';
```

The column of interest is `attrlist` where you'll find all the `cache key`s, this way you'll be able to find what was different in 2 sessions that produced different plans.

Here is the complete repro:

(I use newid() function to get a GUID that I stamp into my query to easily find it later in a plan cache)

```
--set datefirst 1; -- execute the code as it is then uncomment this and comment the next row
set datefirst 7; 

declare @sql nvarchar(4000) =
N'select * /*2343513B-14B6-4BF3-A262-48F645A35A39*/
from s1057.dbo.Nums where n = @n';

declare @p nvarchar(100) = '@n int';

exec sp_executesql @sql, @p, 10;
```

Then use this code to find 2 generated plans with the same `setopts` but different `cache key`:

```
select * 
from sys.syscacheobjects 
where sql like '%2343513B-14B6-4BF3-A262-48F645A35A39%'
  and sql not like '%syscacheobjects%';


SELECT qs.plan_handle, a.attrlist
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS  APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) est
CROSS  APPLY (SELECT epa.attribute + '=' + convert(nvarchar(127), epa.value) + '   '
              FROM   sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(qs.plan_handle) epa
              WHERE  epa.is_cache_key = 1
              ORDER  BY epa.attribute
              FOR    XML PATH('')) AS a(attrlist)
WHERE est.text like '%2343513B-14B6-4BF3-A262-48F645A35A39%'
  and est.text not like '%syscacheobjects%';
```

Here is the picture of what I've done:

[image]

Comment: First I want to say that I appreciate you explaining the setops.  Thank you. In this particular case, it looks like the setops are the same though. The table has been formatted a little better now to reveal that.

Comment: I found other **cache keys** that are not reflected in setopts, for example **date_first**, so I was able to reproduce your case. I updated my answer. Now you can use the code from my answer to see **all the cache keys**, so you'll be able to find what attribute was different and cause the second plan creation.

Comment: I hate to write this comment because your answer has been very instructive already.  In my case, I checked and double-checked.  I am getting identical sets of cache key attributes. (where is_cache_key=1 in m_exec_plan_attributes, as you showed)  Aside from cache_key, is there any other way for the system to decide to create two plans?  Is there a way to display the cache key as a binary value or whatever SQL Server "sees" as the hash for the key? (does it work like that?)

Comment: Another thought.. Could this be a result of a plan recompile?  Maybe schema changes or something caused this.  Is it possible to see the reason that a plan got created?  I ran across this and wondered about it:   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: >>> Could this be a result of a plan recompile<<< Schema changes, etc, that cause plan recompilation, first of all invalidate the old plan, so you cannot see it in a plan cache anymore. I mean, if 100 recompilations of the plan happened, only one plan(and not 100) will be in the cache plan